# from google.protobuf.pyext import _message ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

By using Flask trying to get machine learning results on web page

the application contains code for machine learning tensor-flow

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,request
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
import os
from importlib import reload
def set_keras_backend(backend):

installed Python 3.7 later uninstalled it, and installed Python 3.6,
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.3
h5py==2.7.1
imutils==0.5.2
Jinja2==2.10
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.6
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.5
matplotlib==2.1.2
numpy==1.14.0
numpydoc==0.7.0
pandas==0.22.0
scikit-image==0.13.1
scikit-learn==0.19.1
statsmodels==0.8.0
tensorflow==1.12.0
Theano==1.0.4
six==1.11.0
```

When im trying to run appication from VSCode, getting below error..

> > python application.py

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keras import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the protobuf version as you can see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25072).

Try to install version 3.6.0 using:

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```